# When can a region defined by Bonferroni intervals be smaller than a confidence ellipse?

Tags: confidence-interval, multiple-comparisons

Usually, when finding a confidence region for a bivariate mean, because the confidence ellipse uses the covariance between the two different components, we get a smaller region than the region defined by the Bonferroni intervals for each components.

To get the inverse situation i.e., Bonferroni Region inside the ellipse, would it be enough for the components to be uncorrelated?

If not, then what would be a sufficient condition?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Here's an example of what I'm talking about. In the table below, imagine we use only the last 4 variables.

[image]

If we compare the 95% Bonferroni confidence rectangle for the mean increase in length from 2 to 3 years and the mean increase from 4 to 5 years, with the confidence ellipse for the same means increase, we get the following picture.[image]

Comment: Please explain how you propose to measure "smaller": would it be *contained within*? Larger confidence?  Smaller geometric area?

Comment: @whuber that's a nice point. I was thinking of geometric area.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is "never". First of all, the actual confidence of the Bonferroni region is greater than that if the ellipse. Second, any point inside the ellipse has higher density than any point outside the ellipse, so if you trade an area inside the ellipse and replace it with an equal-confidence region outside the ellipse, that outside area would have to be larger in geometric area.

Comment: @rvl Thanks for the interest. I asked this because I saw such an example. I've edited the question, by adding the data.

Comment: You miscalculated something in your illustration. That rectangle is almost entirely within the ellipse, therefore its confidence coefficient is obviously much smaller than that of the ellipse -- instead, it must be a little bit greater.

Comment: @whuber I've added an example with some data that I've found in a book.